# What is the difference between 'null' or '' (empty string) for the fallback value in React component with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, string, null

I have this Typescript interface:

```
export interface Page {
  description: string | null;
}
```

So `description` field can be `string` or `null`.

What is the difference between `null` vs `''` for setting the fallback value when `data.description` is falsy:

```
<MyComponent
  description={data.description || ''}
 />
```

or:

```
<MyComponent
  description={data.description || null}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.description || ''` - if the `data.description` is *falsy* (either an empty string (`''`) or `null`, it will evaluate to the *fallback* value (an empty string - `''`).

`data.description || null` - if the `data.description` is *falsy* (either an empty string (`''`) or `null`, it will evaluate to the *fallback* value (`null`).

Comment: Thanks but which one should I use?

Comment: @meez Depends on your needs, however probably the `|| ''` version :))